# nginx alpine docker fails without previous ls?

Tags: nginx, permissions, docker, ls, alpine-linux

I want to use radicale with nginx inside a alpine based docker file.
I am currently develop the Dockerfile and noticed a really strange behaivor, maybe somebody can explain this to me.

1. build image

https://gist.github.com/cdpb/7ab1690f30fe6a911dac

2. `docker run -it <id> sh`
3. `su radicale -c 'nginx -t'`

:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

4. `ls -l /var/lib/nginx/tmp`

:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x    2 radicale radicale      4096 Feb 17 11:39 client_body
drwxr-xr-x    2 radicale radicale      4096 Feb 17 11:39 fastcgi
drwxr-xr-x    2 radicale radicale      4096 Feb 17 11:39 proxy
drwxr-xr-x    2 radicale radicale      4096 Feb 17 11:39 scgi
drwxr-xr-x    2 radicale radicale      4096 Feb 17 11:39 uwsgi
```

5. `su radicale -c 'nginx -t'`

:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

so what happens after the `ls`? it should not affect any permissions ... !? Can somebody reproduce this?

Regards

cdpb

UPDATE1: works also with `stat /var/lib/nginx/tmp/*`

UPDATE2: because docker creates a new layer for every command in Dockerfile, I thought that nginx has to be started within the same layer as the chmod/chown layer - didn't fix the problem

UPDATE3: I did the same with a disk installed alpine ( virtualbox ) and the problem didn't occur. So it's more a docker related problem or a special alpine docker one

Comment: What are the contents of `/var/lib/nginx/tmp` _before_ running the first nginx command?

Comment: Please, provide `docker info` output. I have seen such weirdness with overlayfs and devicemapper Docker storage drivers. The only really working driver for me is AUFS.

Comment: See more about Docker storage drivers here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/ (you may want to try some if your host system supports them)

Comment: I am using AUFS. Good point, I'll test same storage backend.
```Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 196
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1000 MiB
Name: lab
```

Comment: Fixed with `overlayfs` rather than `AUFS` - thx for the hint @Vlad Frolov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Moving my answer from the comments.*

Such weirdness is usually related to a [Docker storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/).

There are usually several available Docker storage drivers available on most OSes:

- AUFS (available and default in Ubuntu, Boot2Docker, and also available in Debian testing) - while, AFAIK, it was historically the first FS driver in Docker, AUFS is not part of mainline Linux kernel, so it is not widely adopted.
- OverlayFS - mainline Linux kernel closest alternative to AUFS
- Device Mapper - the slowest, but the most portable Docker storage driver
- etc...

Here is a nice picture comparing different storage drivers from the link posted above.

[image: Pros and Cons of Docker storage drivers]